# Why does F@H not bind to more than one core on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, task-manager, parallel-processing, folding-at-home

I have been contributing to Stanford's [Folding@Home](http://folding.stanford.edu) project for some time with most of the computers I own.

I just installed the Windows client on a new machine running Windows 7, but see that the F@H process only binds to one CPU core. Is this due to it being run on Windows? (I have the 64-bit edition of Windows 7 installed.)

On the Mac and under 64-bit Linux distros, it will run across all available CPU cores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 7 is as fully multi-threaded as Linux, so Windows itself is not the reason.

The explanation must be that the Windows implementation of F@H has fallen behind the Linux one.

Comment: that's what I was afraid the answer would be... oh well. Maybe the upcoming 7.x release of the f@h client will solve that :)

Comment: thats kinda weird... usually the linux app is the one to fall behind.

Answer (score 0):

[BOINC](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/download_all.php) lets you set the max number of cores to use -- you could run BOINC and attach to a project similar to F@h (e.g. [GPUGRID](http://www.gpugrid.net/) or [POEM](http://boinc.fzk.de/poem/)) if you aren't too attached to F@h specifically, until a F@h BOINC version comes out.